# Deleting translate interface strings programmatically or using drush

Tags: 7, drush, i18n-l10n

I need to delete some translated strings added using t() function, I've about 17000 string to delete is there a way to delete it using a SQL query or drush command? in which table those strings are stored?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 7 store translate interface strings in :

1. Table source `locales_source`
2. Table Target `locales_target`