# How to bulk delete translation strings

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I imported some translations using the locale update module but the translations are horrible and it would be better to revert to English.

How do I bulk delete all the imported translations in Drupal 8?

I found an issue on [adding back the D7 translation string deletion option to the UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2503893), but I want to mass delete all strings, not individual strings.

[Drupal 7 version of this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271006/deleting-translate-interface-strings-programmatically-or-using-drush)

**EDIT**: Deleting the language is one approach, but I can't do that because I already have a lot of content translated into the language.  I want to keep the content that I have translated into the language, but delete all the user interface strings that were imported through localization update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you intend to remove ALL strings imported through interface translation, you could execute something like this:

```
// Replace the empty string with your target language code.
$langcode = '';
\Drupal::database()
  ->delete('locales_target')
  ->condition('language', $langcode)
  ->condition('customized', 0)
  ->execute();
```

You may also want to reset the source file history information, so - if you change your mind afterwards - you can re-import the very same translations:

```
\Drupal::database()
  ->delete('locale_file')
  ->condition('language', $langcode)
  ->execute();
```

or

```
locale_translation_file_history_delete([], [$langcode]);
```

As the locale module makes heavy use of static caches, you may run above commands in a dedicated process as, e.g. Drush PHP CLI (`drush php:cli`).

Answer (score 1):

- Suggestion 1

if you want to get rid of all translations of a language, just delete the langauge in */admin/config/regional/language*

- Suggestion 2

  if there are some specific string you want to be not translated, Go to locales_source to identify those strings lids, then execute the following code (devel/php or custom hook_update_N or drush ev...)

```
    
$lids = [4, 5];
db_delete('locales_target')->condition('lid', $lids, 'IN')->execute();
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to delete the language because I have *content* translated into the language that I need to keep.  I want to delete the *interface* translations for the language, but keep the content in the language.

Answer (score 1):

I found http://web.archive.org/web/20230609014802/http://vaerenbergh.com/blog/drupal-8-reimport-all-translation-files the only solution that worked:

```
DELETE FROM key_value WHERE collection='locale.translation_status';
UPDATE locale_file SET timestamp = 0;
UPDATE locale_file SET last_checked = 0;
```

then

```
drush ev "\Drupal::state()->set('locale.translation_last_checked', 0);"
drush cr
drush locale-check && drush locale-update && drush cr
```